# Linear and Non-linear axis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, multiple-axes

I'm the MatLab newbie and I need some help to create a linear and non-linear axis in one chart.
I need to make chart with 2 different X-axes. One X-axis displays 1000/T at the bottom and the second X-axis displays a T at the top of the chart.

**Example figure:**

[image: Example figure]

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem in MatLab?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by simply creating a second axes object at the same place as the first. Let's first create some data:

```
x1 = 1:0.1:3.5;
x2 = 1./x1;
y = (0.5*(x1-2)).^3;
```

Now we can create a normal plot with the first axes, and get the axes handle:

```
plot(x1,y,'-r');
ax(1) = gca;
```

Then we create the second axes object, at the same position as the first, and make the color `none` so it is transparent and the plot from below is still visible. As this adds a second Y axis too, we simply remove the Y ticks of the second axis.

```
ax(2) = axes('Position',ax(1).Position,'XAxisLocation','top','Color','none');
set(ax(2),'YTick',[]);
```

Now lets just format the second X axis as we like. Let's set the limits to the minimum and maximum of the `x2` vector, and make it logarithmic:

```
set(ax(2),'XLim',[min(x2),max(x2)]);
set(ax(2),'XScale','log');
```

Now we still have the problem that the XTicks of `ax(1)` are also displayed at the top, and the XTicks of `ax(2)` are displayed at the bottom. This can be fixed by removing the box around the existing axes and creating a third axis without any ticks but with a box.

```
box(ax(1),'off');
box(ax(2),'off');
ax(3) = axes('Position',ax(1).Position,'XTick',[],'YTick',[],'Box','on','Color','none');
```

Now finally we can link the axes to be able to zoom correctly

```
linkaxes(ax);
```

And that should be it...

Comment: Nice and helpful :) +1

Comment: Thanks, this looks helpful. Unfortunately the top X axis isn't in log scale but  `x2 = 1./x1;` It's any way how to turn top X axis to 1/x scale?

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation for having a graph with two y-axes on the Mathworks website . .

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plotting-with-two-y-axes.html

It should be trivial to covert the concepts to the x-axis.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I need something else. In your example the blue axis is for blue curve and red axis for red curve. My problem is to connect both axes to one curve (graph).

Comment: How about making a fake plot and just setting the second invisible?